# add a class with an exception based on another class name

Tags: class, addition

I need to write an if statement that says if the font element size 3 has a bold child then add class barcode_needed to the bold.  The problem I have having is I need to add an exception.  The exception is if the b statement already has a class called "dont run" then it should not add the barcode_needed class.

(this will have to run through multiple  elements in the code.

```
$("font[size='3'] b").addClass('barcode_needed');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selectors.

```
$("font[size='3']>b:not(.dontRun)").addClass('barcode_needed');
//$("font[size='3'] b:not(.dontRun)").addClass('barcode_needed');
```

This is assuming you have HTML like -

```
<font size="3" ><b class="dontRun">This won't be selected.</b></font>
<font size="3" ><b class="whatever">This will be.</b></font>
```

If `<b>` is not directly below `<font>` then use the second line(commented).